# REST api - URL structure to return related resource based on input resource id

Tags: rest

I am trying to come up with a REST url but am not sure of the best way to structure the url for my scenario.

The api is a calendar service which returns for example some date like Next/Previous BusinessDay details based on a passed in date.

My resource is a collection of calendar dates with some custom fields.

I thought about the below urls

/calendates/{date}/businessdates/{type}

/businessdates/{date}/{type}

here {type} can be next, previous etc. {date} is a passed in date like 10-11-2011

Which of the above 2 examples is better or is there any better way to write this.

thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I follow, why would you need to identify a date by another data and +1 business day? Why don't just use the date itself?

For example:

```
GET /api/v1/calendar/10-11-2011
200 OK
{
    date: "10-11-2011",
    next: "/api/v1/calendar/11-11-2011",
    previous: "/api/v1/calendar/09-11-2011"
}
```

A more refined approach is sending hyperlinks instead of just URIs:

```
{
    date: "10-11-2011",
    links: [
        {
            type: "current-date",
            uri: "/api/v1/calendar/10-11-2011"
        },
        {
            type: "next-date",
            uri: "/api/v1/calendar/11-11-2011"
        },
        {
            type: "previous-date",
            uri: "/api/v1/calendar/09-11-2011"
        }
    ]
}
```

Or if you insist to get it in the same response and expand the resource, then I would use:

```
{

    date: "10-11-2011",
    next: {
        date: "11-11-2011"
    },
    previous: {
        date: "09-11-2011"
    }
}
```

Their combination is possible too:

```
{
    date: "10-11-2011",
    uri: "/api/v1/calendar/10-11-2011"
    next: {
        date: "11-11-2011",
        uri: "/api/v1/calendar/11-11-2011"
    },
    previous: {
        date: "09-11-2011",
        uri: "/api/v1/calendar/09-11-2011"
    }
}
```

or

```
{
    date: "10-11-2011",
    next: {
        date: "11-11-2011",
        links: [
            {
                type: "self",
                uri: "/api/v1/calendar/11-11-2011"
            }
        ]
    },
    previous: {
        date: "09-11-2011",
        links: [
            {
                type: "self",
                uri:  "/api/v1/calendar/09-11-2011"
            }
        ]
    },
    links: [
        {
            type: "self",
            uri: "/api/v1/calendar/10-11-2011"
        }
    ]
}
```